# A question about range projection in von Neumann algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am reading a book about C*-algebra. And I meet with a problem.

Recall the range projection of an operator $a\in B(H)$ is the projection on the closure of $\{a(\eta):\eta\in H\}$(Here, $H$ is a hilbert space). Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra and $a\in M$, **then the author says $(a^{\ast}a)^{1/2}$ and $a$ have the same range projecti**on. Why?

Comment: Would you mind adding a reference to the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the adjoint in the place you put it, the assertion is false: consider $M=B(H)$, $a\in M$ the unilateral shift. Then the range projection of $a$ is $I-E_{11}$, while the range projection of $(a^*a)^{1/2}=I$ is $I$.

But it is true that $a^*$ and $(a^*a)^{1/2}$ have the same range projection. The fastest way to see it is probably to use the polar decomposition: you have $a=v(a^*a)^{1/2}$ for some partial isometry $v$. Then, taking adjoints, $a^*=(a^*a)^{1/2}v$. This shows that any vector in the range of $a^*$ is also in the range of $(a^*a)^{1/2}$. Conversely, $(a^*a)^{1/2}$ is a limit of polynomials in $a^*a$, so any vector in its range is in the closure of the range of $a^*$.

Comment: Shouldn't your last sentence end by "is in the closure of the range of $a^*$"?

Comment: Yes indeed! ${ }$

Comment: :-) Also, your argument requires these polynomials satisfy $p(0)=0$. We could also note that for a projection $p$, we have $pa^*=a^* \iff p\sqrt{a^*a}=\sqrt{a^*a}$ thanks to the polar decomposition that you used anyway. And the range projection of an element $b$ is just the joint of all projections such that $pb=b$. So $a^*$ and $\sqrt{a^*a}$ have the same range projection.

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is basically a more "von Neumann algebra" version of the same argument.